# Trying to pass user input string in formulaR1C1 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My code:

```
   Sub something()
      field = InputBox("Please provide the field name")
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""[""" & Chr(34) & field & Chr(34) & """]=""&RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
   End Sub
```

where:

`RC[-2]` is cell having value `Closed Fund`

`RC[-1]` is cell having value  `or`

`field` is inputted as `Name`

What I got:

> ["Name"]= Closed Fund or

What I want:

> [Name]= Closed Fund or

So I tried tinkering my code as:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""[""" & field & """]=""&RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
```

But I got

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error`

If the problem isn't clear yet, please comment below.

Answer (score 1):

use this formula:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""["" & """ & field & """ & ""]="" & RC[-2] & RC[-1]"
```

Comment: Ahh - I had been thinking the OP was trying to compare something with the values in the other cells, but this makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks so much Scott. It achieved what i wanted.

Comment: @Gunter please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.